# dplyr - Grouping by 2 columns and counting the unique values for one of those columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame

```
id          player  
8297682400  Player1
8297692740  Player1
8255798760  Player1
8255798760  Player1
8255798760  Player1
8255799456  Player2
8255799456  Player2
8255799456  Player2
8255866000  Player2
8255866000  Player2
8255866000  Player2
8255826600  Player1
8255826600  Player1
8255826600  Player1
8255854600  Player2
8255854700  Player1
```

If I use `group_by(player,id)`, I know I can easily count the rows in each group by `%>% mutate(counter=1:n())`

But how can I count the unique `id` values for each player, and "pause" the counting when a duplicate is found?

I want:

```
id          player  id_counter
8297682400  Player1 1
8297692740  Player1 2
8255798760  Player1 3
8255798760  Player1 3
8255798760  Player1 3
8255799456  Player2 1
8255799456  Player2 1
8255799456  Player2 1
8255866000  Player2 2
8255866000  Player2 2
8255866000  Player2 2
8255826600  Player1 4
8255826600  Player1 4
8255826600  Player1 4
8255854600  Player2 3
8255854700  Player1 5
```

Comment: By "pause the counting", I guess you mean `dtt %>% group_by(player) %>% mutate(id_counter = cumsum(!duplicated(id)))`.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `match`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(player) %>%
   mutate(id_counter = match(id, unique(id)))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   player [2]
#           id player  id_counter
#        <dbl> <chr>        <int>
# 1 8297682400 Player1          1
# 2 8297692740 Player1          2
# 3 8255798760 Player1          3
# 4 8255798760 Player1          3
# 5 8255798760 Player1          3
# 6 8255799456 Player2          1
# 7 8255799456 Player2          1
# 8 8255799456 Player2          1
# 9 8255866000 Player2          2
#10 8255866000 Player2          2
#11 8255866000 Player2          2
#12 8255826600 Player1          4
#13 8255826600 Player1          4
#14 8255826600 Player1          4
#15 8255854600 Player2          3
#16 8255854700 Player1          5
```

---

Or by converting to `factor` and coerce it to `integer`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(player) %>% 
   mutate(id_counter = as.integer(factor(id, levels = unique(id))))
```